# Running Xcode 11 on early 2011 Macbook Pro | Help Needed

Tags: macbook-pro, xcode

I need to run an ios 13 simulator on my mac. Currently, I'm on El Capitan with Xcode 8.2. My hardware is not compatible with Catalina or Mojave. Highest I can upgrade to is High Sierra. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Your only possible workaround is to use the [dosDude patcher](http://dosdude1.com/mojave/) to allow your machine to run Mojave.
This is really not advised, because without a Metal2-capable GPU your machine will run very slowly.

Your only 'real' solution is a newer Mac.